# Not getting Facebook emailid for some users in my app

Tags: email, facebook-graph-api

I am using application access token to get user inforamation

https://graph.facebook.com/100003159076005?fields=friends,email,username&access_token=XXXXXXXXXX.

Using the same pattern for 
https://graph.facebook.com/100000122482221?fields=friends,email,username&access_token=XXXXXXXX
I am able to get user emailid

Issue is that, I am not able to fetch emailid for all users.

Thanks

Rohit Bansal

Comment: Do you have asked these users for `email` permission beforehand? If you are using your app token, you will only get the email for those you have given you the permission at some point before.

Comment: YES, We have already included email permission while asking for user to authorize our app. FB.login(function(response) {
   //do code here
  }, {
   scope : 'email,user_status,friends_status,publish_stream'
  });

Comment: Maybe the users have revoked permissions for your app?